# asterisk : add application

Tags: asterisk

I want to know the way to add new asterisk applications and modules.For example I don't have the SetGlobalVar application in my asterisk machine.I want to add that.Is there any way.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

As for `SetGlobalVar` you can use `Set` with `g` option as described in [Asterisk wiki](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page=Asterisk+cmd+SetGlobalVar). Instead of writing such application write simple program that changes dialplan.

If you want to add some other thing to Asterisk there is simpler option than adding application: use [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI) with your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `GLOBAL()` function.  For example:

```
exten => 1234,1,Set(GLOBAL(MY_GLOBAL_VAR)=value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely off-base here, but, I believe what the OP is asking for is how to actually load this module.. Assuming your asterisk distribution shipped with func_global, just do "module load func_global.so". If you want it to load on asterisk startup, add it to your modules.conf.

If your distribution doesn't package asterisk with that module, then you're going to have to either rebuild the package and include it, or build just that module from vanilla asterisk sources, then copy it over to your lib/modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Asterisk version, that application may actually not even exist any more. I believe it was removed with Asterisk 1.8 and following.